# Why does expression in ng-disabled not work?

Tags: angularjs

What does this:

`ng-disabled="login == ''"`

not disable the button when the input field `login` is empty?

```
<html ng-app="mainApp">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>

    </head>    
    <body ng-controller="mainController">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    LOGIN
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="login">Login</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" ng-model="login">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputPassword">Passowrd</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="login == ''"  class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
                            var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

                            mainApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
                            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `undefined == '' // false` or am I misunderstanding your question? Have you tried `ng-disabled="!login"`

Comment: ok, yes, that works, but so does `login == 'ok'` in the sense that when you type in `ok` then the button is disabled, I would think == '' would return true if it were empty, ok, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a form object in your controller which would hold each model property/field, and then check if the field (`login`) equates and empty string.

```
...
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" ng-model="form.login">
...
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.login === ''" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
....
```

**Controller**

```
mainApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.form = {
        login: ''
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/x2fe8kop/)**